# Определить текст выбранного элемента ListView

Tags: android, listview

Вопрос простой, но у меня не получается
Суть в том, что мне нужно определить текст выбранного элемента ListView

ListView у меня заполняется парсером из XML файла, вот код:

```
public class Marsh extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rasp);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.troll);
            while (parser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
            {
                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("bus"))
                {
                        list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                }
           parser.next();
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Ошибка при загрузке XML-документа: " + t.toString(), 4000)
                    .show();
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

        OnItemClickListener itemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id)  {
                  //Что мне тут написать
            }
        };
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
    }   
}
```

Comment: штука в том, что listView сам не знает текст. Он все спрашивает у адаптера. Вот и Вы спросите. Номер элемента Вам известен.

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```